# Locate and extract only particular tag in HTML response Java

Tags: java, html

I am trying to find the gender of a name by using website "http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php".I was able to pass parameters using get request and get the html page as response like the following

```
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?name=sarah");
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        int status = connection.getResponseCode();
        //System.out.println(status);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        rd.close();

     //program prints whole HTML page as response.
```

The HTML response has a element like "**It's a girl!**" where the required result located.How do i extract only the above string and prints whether the input parameter is a boy or girl.Example:sarah is a girl..

Comment: How do you identify where this text is?

Comment: The HTML response page has tag like <b> It's a girl! </b>

Comment: If it's got a unique path, then you could use XPath to pull out the text that you need.

Comment: Here i have to extract only string like "It's a girl", i can not rely on tag <b> because there are many other <b> tags.Is it possible to extract only string through XPath?

Answer (score 0):

Add [jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to your project. Use it to convert HTML to XML. After that, you can use the standard XML tools like [JDOM 2](http://www.jdom.org/) or [Jaxen](http://www.jaxen.org/) to examine the data.

What you neeed to do is look at the HTML code and determine a unique path that allows you to identify the desired element. There are no simple solutions here. But some pointers:

- Look for elements with `id` attributes since they are unique
- Look for elements that are rare.
- Look for unique texts